# Generics and ArrayList to implement a priority queue

Tags: java

I am stuck on an assignment which includes generics and `ArrayList`. The assignment is to implement a priority queue capable of holding objects of an arbitrary type `T` by defining a priority queue class that implements the queue with an `ArrayList`.

The method to be supported is `Add(item, priority)`

And depending on the priority `remove()` removes the highest item in the priority list.

I created the Generic Class with the type being `T`, declared `private T data`. Used multiple constructors to set data. Now I am stuck on how to use this class and Use `ArrayList`, as I am not sure you can `add(string, integer)` in an `ArrayList` let alone iterate through it.

Any tips and ideas on how to approach this homework will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `Comparable` and `Comparator` interfaces in order to support the comparison of the elements. Note that in Java `PriorityQueue` class [there is a constructor that accepts a `Comparator<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue%28int,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: Check the following links (the tutorial of the `Queue` implementations and the documentation for `PriorityQueue`, `Comparable` and `Comparator` ): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: At SO, you should usually include the code you have (possibly clean it up first if it's messy...), though with homework this can have its own problems... Also hint: you need an inner or a nested class, which will have item and priority properties. You can then store instances of this class in the `ArrayList`, which you should keep "manually" sorted always.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to wrap the data and its priority inside another object, only used internally by your PriorityQueue (just like a LinkedList uses nodes that wrap the data and a pointer to the next node).

So `priorityQueue(T data, int priority)` would end up being implemented as

```
Node node = new Node(data, priority);
// find the position where the node must be inserted
arrayList.add(position, node);
```

Comment: Thank you all! I will use your guidance and come back if I have more questions!